# What is the difference between ”current“ and “prev” in the “__schedule” function, why not use current directly?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

From the kernel source code:

```
static void __sched notrace __schedule(bool preempt)
{
        struct task_struct *prev, *next;
        unsigned long *switch_count;
        struct rq_flags rf;
        struct rq *rq;
        int cpu;

        cpu = smp_processor_id();
        rq = cpu_rq(cpu);
        prev = rq->curr;  // <=================(1)
        .....
```

What is the difference between `current` and `prev` at the line (1) above?

Adding a `printk()` after that line:

```
static void __sched notrace __schedule(bool preempt)
{
        struct task_struct *prev, *next;
        unsigned long *switch_count;
        struct rq_flags rf;
        struct rq *rq;
        int cpu;

        cpu = smp_processor_id();
        rq = cpu_rq(cpu);
        prev = rq->curr;
        //if(prev->pid != current->pid)
        printk("the prev->pid =%d, The current = %d \n", prev->pid, current->pid); // <===========(2)

        schedule_debug(prev);

        if (sched_feat(HRTICK))
                hrtick_clear(rq);
```

The resulting logs from (2) are:

```
[ 4184.164038] the prev->pid =0, The current = 0 
[ 4184.165365] the prev->pid =12, The current = 12 
[ 4186.008068] the prev->pid =0, The current = 0 
[ 4186.009396] the prev->pid =30, The current = 30 
[ 4188.008046] the prev->pid =0, The current = 0 
[ 4188.009334] the prev->pid =30, The current = 30 
[ 4188.164041] the prev->pid =0, The current = 0 
[ 4188.165315] the prev->pid =12, The current = 12 
[ 4190.008047] the prev->pid =0, The current = 0 
[ 4190.009431] the prev->pid =30, The current = 30
```

The displays show that the result is the same.

- why not use `current`
  instead of

```
    cpu = smp_processor_id(); 
    rq = cpu_rq(cpu); 
    prev = rq->curr;
```

Comment: The way its done disables preemption.  Using `current` could have race conditions.

Answer (score 5):

`prev` is a variable used for temporarily remembering the current task when it's being swapped with a new one in the runqueue. Of course, if you look at `prev` exactly right after doing `prev = rq->curr` you will have `prev == rq->curr == current`, since it was just assigned to it.

If you want to inspect which task is being picked to run next, you'll have to look after that, when `__schedule()` does:

```c
next = pick_next_task(rq, prev, &rf);
```

Now `next` will be different from `prev`.

Comment: The struct member is `curr`, not `current`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli 
Thanks for your answer, what I am wondering is why not use
 ```current```
instead of 
```
       cpu = smp_processor_id();
        rq = cpu_rq(cpu);
        prev = rq->curr;
```

Comment: @Joeys look at it this way: the scheduler algorithm deals with run queues, and it should work whether or not the global `current` variable exists. This way, the structures and the code implementing the algorithm are not dependent on external factors. The scheduler does not care that `current` exists, it's just a global variable (actually a macro) that exists for convenience when other parts of kernel code need it.